# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript

todo bien hasta que trato de colocar lo que viene del template con
itemProducto.cantidad
me sale este error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')**

```
<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" class="PRE_" id="PRE_${id}"  min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}"  min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

los trato de obtener asi `document.querySelector('.PRE_').value` `document.querySelector("PRE_"+id).value=itemProducto.cantidad;`
en la funcion los productos que son objetos, lo meto dentro del array
arreglos

```
function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
  
    

    const button=e.target
    const item = button.closest('.tr')
    const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
  const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
 
  const Productos = {
    id: id_prod,
    
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    precio:0,
    cantidad:1
  }
const arreglos=[}
  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)

  let itemProducto =arreglo.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(arreglo)
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(itemProducto)
    if(itemProducto){
       //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
      if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemProducto.cantidad){
        return;
      }
      console.log("Repetido");
     itemProducto.cantidad++;
  console.log(document.querySelector('.PRE_').value)
     //document.querySelector("PRE_"+id).value=itemProducto.cantidad;
    }
    else{
      console.log("NO Repetido");
      itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
     itemCarrito.cantidad=1
     itemCarrito.precio
      carrito.push(itemCarrito);
      
      //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
      carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
    }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Es JS puro o estás trabajando con Vue o React?

Comment: es JS Vanilla o Js puro

Comment: el selector de ID de un elemento es con # prueba así `document.querySelector("#PRE_"+id).value=itemProducto.cantidad;`

Comment: en todo caso si estás seleccionando por Id es mejor usar `document.getElementById`, es ligeramente mas rápido aunque no por mucho

Comment: Gracias no sabia, que era mas rapido